# Cannot mount swap partition at boot on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, swap, amazon-linux

I am trying to mount swap partition in `etc/fstab` on Amazon Linux 2, but it doesn't work on the boot-up process.

here the steps I have followed:

- create swap file: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1048576`
- change permission to 600: `chmod 600 /swapfile`
- setup swapfile: `mkswap /swapfile`
- add swap to fstab: `UUID=90c0668b-6bca-4dd7-bdca-b62c19e2a911      none    swap    sw 0 0`
- reboot

After reboot, nothing happened...

I have also tried to mount it with:

```
/swapfile       none    swap    sw 0 0
```

but still not working.

Manually, using `swapon` command it's working perfectly...

Comment: I did this on AL1, try the steps in my [blog post about adding swap to Amazon Linux](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/adding-swap-space-ec2-amazon-linux-instance/), which look pretty similar to yours but some differences there.

Comment: Thanks @tim, I would highlight a small detail about `dd` command:
I have used `bs= 1024 count=1048576` because using `bs=1M count=1024` gave me memory allocation problems.

Comment: What does `swapon -a` say?